# mysql subquery and having max value of subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, max, having

```
SELECT plaka, party_id, sum(inf) i 
  FROM party_sehir
 GROUP BY party_id, plaka
```

This is my sub-query and the results are:

```
plaka   party_id   i 
34      1          42
34      2          9
35      1          11
35      2          26
```

from these results I want to get maximum `i` of every `plaka` and rows `party_id`, like this:

```
plaka  party_id    i 
34     1           42
35     2           26
```

I mean the maximum for each `plaka`. I also tried:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( SELECT plaka, party_id, sum(inf) i 
           FROM party_sehir
          GROUP BY party_id, plaka ) t1 
 GROUP BY plaka  
HAVING i >= max(i)
```

It didn't work; is anyone able to help?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs a longer query, like

```
select plaka,party_id, i 
from
(SELECT plaka,party_id, sum(inf) i FROM party_sehir
 GROUP BY  party_id, plaka) sum_group
where (i,plaka) in (
SELECT max(i), plaka
 FROM (SELECT plaka,party_id, sum(inf) i FROM party_sehir
 GROUP BY  party_id, plaka) t1 group by plaka )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try group by for your solution

```
SELECT plaka ,party_id   , max( `i` ) FROM `party_sehir` GROUP BY `plaka`
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `party_sehir` AS s1 WHERE s1.i = (SELECT max( `i` ) FROM party_sehir AS  
   s2  WHERE s1.plaka = s2.plaka ) GROUP BY `plaka`
```